# What is the use of "items" property in MatMenu of angular/material2?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the Angular material, MatMenu documentation https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api, the API has a "items" property which is documented like an attribute of type QueryList to the MatMenu component.

In the Angular documentation for QueryList, https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList, the live example shows the @ContentChildren(Item) items: QueryList returns a QueryList of type "Item" component inside the "container" template. And, when I checked out the code for MatMenu directive https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/menu/menu-directive.ts. They are also getting a list of all the mat-menu-item inside the MatMenu component.

Few questions, I have is:

- How to use "items" property?
- Can we dynamically set mat-menu-items using this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the `items` property of the menu on an instance of the `MatMenu` type. In order to get a hold of the menu's reference, you can add a `@ViewChild` property for it inside your `.ts` file.

HTML:

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item> Settings </button>
    <button mat-menu-item> Help </button>
</mat-menu>
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of appMenu.items">
        {{item.getLabel()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('appMenu') appMenu: MatMenu;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.appMenu.items);
    }
}
```

Because the `QueryList` implements an iterable interface, it can be used in both ES6 javascript `for (var i of items)` loops as well as in Angular templates with `*ngFor="let i of menu.items"`. [The documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) states the following about the `QueryList`

> An unmodifiable list of items that Angular keeps up to date when the state of the application changes.

Which leads me to believe that you are not supposed to change the contents of this list dynamically.

Comment: items is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understand your question, probably not but this is what I have in my HTML code:

```html
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./login']">Login</button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./register']">Register</button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./logout']"> Logout </button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./profile']"> Profile </button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./main']"> Main </button>
</mat-menu>
```

item is just css, so  you can use it to create menu items. It has nothing to do with the content of the item.

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you please elaborate on how can we change the CSS using "items" property of MatMenu directive?

Comment: <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./login']">{{key.name}}</button>    In the component you

Comment: menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./login']">{{dynamicName}}</button>    </div> In the component you can create an array this.dynamicName = dynamicname  I still am not sure if this is what u mean...

Comment: I am not sure if you can use items: QueryList<MatMenuItem> to change it dynamically, maybe only to get the list of the items. not sure.

Comment: I am sure that list of menu items inside the MatMenu component is not two way binded. I am inclined to believe that there is something wrong with the documentation.

Comment: y you might be right, but are any other material features two way binded like you want to do? I thought just using {{}} does the trick generally? I am asking this cause I really don't know ;)

Comment: This would have worked if the expected type was string. But, the expected type is a QueryList of MatMenuItem